# Rails: Using JQuery for post request instead of link_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Right now, there is a "votes" model in my Rails app. Each post on a page has an upvote button, which is currently written as:

```
<%= link_to "✓", votes_path(:vote => {:post_id => post.id, :up => false}), :method => :post %>
```

Where post_id is the post that the vote is linked to and up is a boolean saying that the vote is true. I'm trying to use JQuery instead of link_to so that the page doesn't reload every time someone votes. However, I don't understand what the AJAX post request looks like to interface with the database model.

Edit: Votes controller:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { flash[:notice] = "Vote created"} # and render your <action>.js file}
    end
    @vote = Vote.where(:post_id => params[:vote][:post_id], :user_id => current_user.id).first
    if @vote
        @vote.up = params[:vote][:up]
        @vote.save
    else
        @vote = current_user.votes.create(vote_params)
    end 
    redirect_to :back
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `remote: true` option for ajax call.

```
<%= link_to "✓", votes_path(:vote => {:post_id => post.id, :up => false}, :format => :js), :method => :post, remote: true %>
```

It will generate an ajax call to your controller. You can then manipulate your action correspondingly.

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
 format.js { flash[:notice] = "Vote created"} # and render your <action>.js file
end
```

**Update**

```
def create
    @vote = Vote.where(:post_id => params[:vote][:post_id], :user_id => current_user.id).first
    if @vote
        @vote.up = params[:vote][:up]
        @vote.save
    else
        @vote = current_user.votes.create(vote_params)
    end 
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { flash[:notice] = "Vote created"} # and render your <action>.js file}
    end
end
```

It should work, Let me know

And also check this..

Your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` should contain.

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And your erb should contain

`<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs" %>`

Comment: The AJAX request seems to work out right, but I'm confused about the respond_to action. When I add it to the votes controller, I get this error message:



`Missing template votes/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.`

Comment: This obviously refers to the fact that there's no votes view, but it really shouldn't be looking for one. I edited the main post with my votes controller

Comment: Do you have an html view file for your action?

Comment: ofc, format.js should handle the request. It shouldnt be looking for html file

Comment: It's still giving me the same error. What exactly is format.js going to be? Is it a votes.js.erb to be saved in the views or a votes.js file in the asset pipeline?

Comment: It will look for votes.js.erb or votes.js, either will work. And check the latest update

Comment: Created a blank votes.js.erb in the views/pages folder where the votes will be rendered. Just added the JQuery inclusion. Still gives me the error looking for a template.

Comment: your Gemfile should contain `gem 'jquery-rails'`. If it contains all, It should be working, I don't see any other reason for it to be looking for html, rather than js.

Comment: Hold on. Just noticed something interesting. The AJAX post only sends for the first post on the page. The others return the error.

Comment: And to force it to make a js request, you can add format to your link_to `votes_path(:vote => {:post_id => post.id, :up => false}, :format => :js)`

Answer (score -1):

You can reuse `link_to` to `post` a remote request without loading like:

```
<%= link_to "✓", votes_path(:vote => {:post_id => post.id, :up => false}), :method => :post, remote: true %>.
```

You shall have to write a `<your_action_name>.js.erb` for the purpose though.